# How can I find the sequence of this table?

Tags: sequences-and-series, python

how can I find the sequence of this table?
I know that the algorithm I can use is binary search and that the complexity is O(log n), but I don't know how that sequence can be generated.

We have a vector of ordered integers of size 1,000,000. As shown in the example:

| Posición | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | -321 |
| 1 | -21 |
| 2 | 321 |
| 3 | 1561 |
| ... | ... |
| 99,999 | 1,843,138 |
| 1,000,000 | 31,351,321 |

(a) Write an algorithm to find the position of the number 356,321.

(b) Describe the complexity of the algorithm that was implemented.

Comment: I don’t think you’re supposed to know the exact sequence of values.  All that matters is that they are increasing.

Comment: @mjqxxxx So it doesn't matter what numbers are in the array of size 1,000,000?, other than finding what position the number 356,321 is in?

Comment: You say you know you are supposed to use binary search, so write an algorithm that does that.  You say you know the complexity, so justify that is the complexity of your algorithm.  Presumably you are told that the values are monotonic, else binary search would fail.

Comment: Based on your comment, no, you are not asked for other numbers in the table.  You are only asked for the position that value is in.

Comment: The problem composer is in the wrong line of work.  The posted question is not a Math problem.  You are trying to find *some* pattern that is consistent with the data.  Even if such a pattern is found, there is no guarantee that this is the pattern that the problem composer had in mind.